# NodeJs - keep index.ejs in the root folder and not in views folder

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am running a very simple node app. I have my app.js in my root folder and my index.ejs, contact.ejs and about.ejs in the views folder.

When I run this on my localhost it works like a charm. I am trying to put the app onto a2hosting but a2hosting it does not find the index.ejs file at all however if i navigate to the about or contact on a2hosting I see them perfectly.

How can I move my index.ejs to my root folder which I suspect is the problem on a2hosting.

Here is my app.js file:

```
    var express             = require("express"),
      app                   = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
const path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/css', express.static('css'));

//Root Route
app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("index");
});

app.get("/contact", function(req, res){
    // res.send("You have reached the contact page");
    res.render("contact");
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res){
    // res.send("You have reached the contact page");
    res.render("about");
});

app.listen(3000, process.env.IP, function(){
    // process.env.PORT
  console.log("Wayne's Server has started");
});
```

I have tried moving my index.ejs file to the root folder and tried changing

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
      res.render("index");
    });
```

to

```
app.get("../", function(req, res){
      res.render("index");
    });
```

and to

```
app.get("./", function(req, res){
      res.render("index");
    });
```

but I cannot get it to work. I assume once I get it working on my localhost I should get it working on the web hosting service.

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: share your project Structure

Comment: what is the error in the console/logs. try checking logs

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the views folder and in inside that folder create the file.
Your project structure supposed to be:

```
ProjectDemo 
  - models
    - xyz.js
  - views
    - index.ejs
    - about.ejs
    - contact.ejs
  - routes
    - routes.js
  - index.js
```